# Problema al mostrar una fotografia que ocupe la pantalla css

Tags: html, css

Hola quiero implementar un css con html que me muestre una foto de izquierda a derecha de la pantalla sin que me aparezca una barra desplazadora.Lo que pasa es que me queda un marco blanco pequeñito tanto arriba como a los lados. Y también mostrar texto encima de la foto y que este centrado.

```css
.centrado {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 6em;
  font-family: Alegreya Sans;
  color: white;
}

.imagen1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" class="imagen1" />
  <div class="centrado">TEXTO</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El borde que se te queda alrededor de la imagen viene dado por el css base que se le aplica al body de forma automática, se arreglaría añadiendo un estilo que quitara tanto el `margin` como el `padding`.

Por otra parte, el texto se ve de esa forma por la posición absoluta que le has dado, para centrarlo basta con que el `div` con clase `contenedor` tenga un alineamiento de texto centrado.

Te dejo el ejemplo con eso cambiado:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.contenedor {
  text-align: center;
}

.centrado {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 6em;
  font-family: Alegreya Sans;
  color: black;
}

.imagen1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="centrado">TEXTO</div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="imagen1" />
</div>
```

**Edit**

Después de la aclaración de @lois6b y tú confirmación, dejo el código con lo que querías.

Para que la imagen ocupe todo el ancho, es lo que dije más arriba, el `margin` y `padding` del `body`. 
Por otra parte, centrar el texto en la imagen lo puedes hacer de varias formas. Sin tocar el html, la forma más fácil sería dándole estas propiedades al contendor:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

De esta manera, el contenido del `div` queda centrado horizontal y verticalmente independientemente del tamaño del `div`,aunque lo hagas más grande o más pequeño el texto seguirá centrado, de igual manera, aunque el texto ocupe más de una línea, se mantendrá centrado.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.centrado {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 6em;
  font-family: Alegreya Sans;
  color: white;
}

.imagen1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" class="imagen1" />
  <div class="centrado">TEXTO</div>
</div>
```

El `overflow: hidden` es por si quieres cambiar el tamaño del `div` y no el de la imagen, pero si el texto ocupa más de este tamaño también se verá cortado.

El texto tiene una posición absoluta para verse por encima de la imagen, podría arreglarse también cambiando el `z-index`.

Comment: A lo que me refería es por encima texto y la imagen de fondo, pero no quier que la imagen ocupe todo el fondo simplemente un trozo de la pagina pero que vaya de lado a lado de esta.

Comment: He editado añadiendo cómo tendría que ser con tu aclaración. Siento el malentendido :)